# Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier Error?

Tags: sql-server

I would like to pass nvarchar values to uniqueidentifier.

Eg.:

```
Declare @test nvarchar(max);
set @test =  '''' + '77494371-30c1-4d2e-8dea-58dbefb325cc' + '''' --+ ',' + '''' + 'cb4229a2-76f8-4d68-aef7-f0bae089b382' + '''';
print @test;

Select * from Table1 where ID in (@test);
```

I tried to pass above condition. That time i am facing below error:

```
'77494371-30c1-4d2e-8dea-58dbefb325cc','cb4229a2-76f8-4d68-aef7-f0bae089b382'
Msg 8169, Level 16, State 2, Line 5
Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.
```

IF any way to pass Multiple uniqueidentifier values to `Where In` condition.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: You cannot use a variable containing string like `'X','Y','Z'` in an in clause and think that it will fetch the 3 values. It will try to find one value, `'X','Y','Z'`. You have to either create dynamic SQL, or use some kind of table structure like table variable.

Answer (score 1):

Currently you query will be parsed as

```
Select * 
from Table1 
where ID in ('''77494371-30c1-4d2e-8dea-58dbefb325cc','cb4229a2-76f8-4d68-aef7-f0bae089b382''')
```

Where your input `'''77494371-30c1-4d2e-8dea-58dbefb325cc','cb4229a2-76f8-4d68-aef7-f0bae089b382'''` is definitely not a `Unique Identifier` so you are getting that error

I will suggest you to go with the below approach

```
Declare @guid_col table(guid_col uniqueidentifier);

insert into @guid_col 
values('77494371-30c1-4d2e-8dea-58dbefb325cc'),
       ('cb4229a2-76f8-4d68-aef7-f0bae089b382')

Select * from Table1 where ID in(select guid_col from @guid_col)
```

or you need a *split string* function in which you need to split the comma separated values in `@test` variable and use it in `Where` clause. For info on split string function check the below link

[**Split strings the right way – or the next best way**](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
Declare @test nvarchar(max), @xml XML;
set @test =  '77494371-30c1-4d2e-8dea-58dbefb325cc,cb4229a2-76f8-4d68-aef7-f0bae089b382';

set @xml = N'<root><r>' + replace(@test,',','</r><r>') + '</r></root>'


Select * from Table1 
where ID in ( select r.value('.','varchar(max)') as item
              from @xml.nodes('//root/r') as records(r)
            );
```